# store loop value in array

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I  want to store all value in a array and get out from the loop is it possible?

```
<?php
    $a=array('a', 'b', 'c');
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
        {
            $c = array();
            $c[$i] = $b;     
        }

        print_r($c);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just `$c = $a;` and `print_r($c);` ??

Comment: What are you trying to do? Regarding your code you're expecting `$c = array('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c');`?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake the array variable `$c=array()` should be out side of loop

```
<?php

   $a=array('a','b','c');

   $c=array();
   // for loop
   for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
       $c[$i]=$a[$i];
   }
   // forEach loop
   foreach ($a as $b){
         $c[]=$b;
   }
   // while loop
   $x=0;
   while($x<count($a)){
          $c[$x]=$a[$x];
          $x++;
   }

  print_r($c);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Moved `$c = array();`  from inside forloop into outside the forloop.

```
<?php
   $a=array('a','b','c');
    foreach($a as $b){
        $c = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){                
            $c[$i]=$b;
        }
        print_r($c);
    }
?>
```

Comment: no its wrong. in this i am getting `$c[0]==123` and `$c[1]==123`. I dont want like this. I want `$c[0]==1`,`$c[1]==2`,`$c[2]==3`. Like this

Answer (score 0):

Why you are defining array at each iteration?

```
<?php
$a=array('a','b','c');
foreach($a as $b){
    $c=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
    $c[$i]=$b;     
}
print_r($c);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to storing values in empty array using foreach.

```
$coll_courses = array();
foreach ($courses as $req_courses){
    $coll_courses[] = $req_courses;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($coll_courses);
```